# How to make the bookmark bar of Google Chrome bigger?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have many bookmarks that I'd like to show in the bookmark bar.  How to make the bookmark bar of Google Chrome bigger, for example, let it show two rows of bookmark icons? If impossible, is there some extension that can essential help me having a big bookmark bar?

Comment: Any updates on this so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially no. There are workarounds though, like grouping bookmarks in folders or using extensions.

Some ideas of extensions: [Bookmark Bar Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pcacnohhaamchlpkihbdifkfjjimcnkl) which lets you switch between multiple bookmark bars or [Iconized Bookmarks Bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcckkbjlhigedglildibmgomeannjaid) which helps you gain space on the bookmarks bar by adding icons instead of text.

Comment: You can edit out the text for any chrome bookmark, which leaves just the icon, right click on any bookmark and select edit, blank the name field, this works for url bookmarks.

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer is, [it's not possible](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/7df6bd854a34e4f5?pli=1). If you want to check out all of the Google Chrome bookmark extensions, just search Google's official Web Store for [bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/bookmark).

Your best bet is to sort them into folders and name the folders short one word names. This is what I did when I realized that I was running out of space.

Here is example of my Chrome bookmark bar:

[image: chrome bookmarks bar with folders]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to save space, just use the icons by entering in blank names for the bookmarks you often use on your bookmark bar. :)

[image: Example]

Comment: I have more than 200 such icons already.

Answer (score 4):

I has same problem, I installed https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-sidebar/jdbnofccmhefkmjbkkdkfiicjkgofkdh?hl=en
for convenient i move my bookmarks (folders) to "other bookmarks" to separate bookmarks and conclude that you can use native other bookmarks, 
it faster and lighter. But it was very convenient that can change height of bookmarks panel

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I just edit the descriptions to make them smaller, allowing more to fit.  Try simple 3 character abbreviations.  Right click on the bookmark in the bar to edit it.

Comment: That does not work for me. I have more.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done to save space is basically the same as what the previous person wrote;  i.e. edit the bookmarks so that they're *only the icons* and not the text (except in a couple cases where the icons were the same [like for multiple instances where the bookmark in question goes to a google sheets document, or a folder].[image: picture of my bookmarks bar]

Comment: there are also extensions you can get to make your own icons, which helps in differentiating folders and icons that would otherwise be identical

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh?hl=en-US

and

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo?hl=en

Comment: Please don't duplicate an existing answer. Your answer is likely to be deleted. Either show a new solution or find some other question to answer. Read [answer] before answering.

Comment: I do this too, sometimes shortening a folder's name to as short as a single character '音'. But on top of that, I still feel the one-row space as not sufficient for my need.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to look through the Chrome Web Store (to try to find an extension for another question) and I found the following:

1. [Bookmarks Bar Skipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-bar-switcher/lcaelgondnfehcambmdhhfokjknhfahc?hl=en)

   - This extension was last edited on Feb. 10, 2019.
2. [Swappable](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swappable/ppbbcakfobecheiebijejadegfflgcke?hl=en)

   - This extension was last edited on March 8, 2015.

I have not actually tested them out, but based on what a few associates of mine have stated, 'Bookmarks Bar Skipper' is the better of the two.

Answer (score 0):

My way of Doing is

1.Edit each bookmark and remove the site's name. Remembering the site's logo is easier than remembering the site's name.

2. I've bookmarked few of my documents in google drive. Here the problem is even if you remove the name, It'll show document icon. So while editing the bookmark, instead of keeping a name, I add an emoji(Delete name and copy+paste an emoji which is relevant to the content) Plenty of emojis are available so that we can use accordingly. For some document I put alt code like hexagon etc.,
3. Can anyone guess what is the difference between these two bookmarks. How I made more bookmarks to accommodate the same bookmark?

(1)
https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/PdvLmON0xI5VeplgqFd5mARs5rVHSDusFsAzcF6GVRn

(2)
https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/MgW2tDBhMOmBIpOq6eEU213PKQStTLrvkKif3BUU1Sv

The idea is very simple. The first one's display resolution is 1440 X 900.
In the second one increased the display resolution is 1920 X1080. So, if you increase the display resolution in display settings, more number of bookmarks can be accommodated.

4. If you prefer dock on the left side and if your OS allows 'auto-hide' feature, then make it auto-hidable. Since our bookmark is only logos, the width occupied by the dock gives extra space for few more bookmarks.
5. Apart from this, You can add your preferred shortcuts in google chrome home page.
6. On the top right corner of the chrome window you have google apps icon( 9 dots). All the google apps can be directly accessed from here.
7. You can add this extension from google chrome extension and add as many shortcuts as you want of your preferred site.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcuts-for-google/baohinapilmkigilbbbcccncoljkdpnd?hl=en-GB

(May be the same kind of more extensions are available I think)

8. As one of the google home page short cut you can add **google bookmark.** So, with two clicks, you can reach your site.
   https://www.google.co.in/bookmarks/
9. Last but not least, you can add **google keep** extension as well and organize with different colors and lables.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi?hl=en-GB

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Changing display resolution so that the logical resolution differs from the physical one is creative but may provoque other problems. The other point is that the user question was to make the bar bigger not to make the entries smaller so that more links fit in there. I have difficulties in considering this as an answer and would rather placed that into the comments section.

Answer (score -1):

I put them in alphabetical folders with sub-folders in those and then dragged the bookmarks into the sub-folders. Drag them by the folder icon next to the address bar, but most of you probably already know how to do that. You can make the sub-folder and then drag it on top of the alphabetical folder.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The author wants all of the bookmarks accessible from the bookmark bar, not buried away in a folder.