# Enlarge Bookmark Bar Icons in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, icons, bookmarks, accessibility

I would like to increase the size of the icons in Chrome's bookmark bar. Zooming in the page content does not affect the size of the icons. The answers to the most related question are all out of date: [How to make the bookmark bar of Google Chrome bigger?](https://superuser.com/questions/433122/how-to-make-the-bookmark-bar-of-google-chrome-bigger)

I see two possible routes:

1. Modify the **entire GUI size**, while maintaining resolution. I cannot find any chrome setting or extension to do so.
2. Modify the **size of the icons on the bookmark bar**. I cannot find any
   chrome setting or extension to do so.

I use both MacOS and Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to apply the setting in a cross-platform manner, if possible, but any per-platform solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked all over the place (mostly) and could not find anything in the way you are wanting it done. All I can say is go to chrome://settings/display, and change the display size of the internal screen.

It should work on your device, however, I would not know since I do not use MacOS or Ubuntu and I do not have experience using said operating systems.

Google does have a G Suite Developer Hub (script.google.com), which allows the user to code/create Chrome Add-ons. Maybe you can just create an add-on if all else fails.

Edited 102319: I have found a Chrome Extension that MIGHT work (I can not currently check right now due to me using a Chromebook right now)

- [Fluid Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fluid-bookmarks/haandfikjmhahlpkhapifhkanmdaakop?hl=en)

The page of the Fluid Bookmarks extension states that

> Bookmarks bar is fully customizable to meet all of your needs:
>     - Change the background color
>     - Change the text color
>     - Change the border color
>     - Change the bookmark hover color
>     - Change the font size
>     - Choose between bookmark names only, bookmark icons only, or both
>     - Choose how long your mouse must stay in the address bar area for the 
>             bookmarks bar to drop down.
>     Supported on both Windows and Mac!

Comment: Can you be more explicit about 'change the display size of the internal screen'? I couldn't find any such setting in `chrome://settings/display`

Comment: Maybe is only showing for me,do to the fact that I am using a laptop. Check the post that I just edited for a picture.

Comment: Fluid bookmarks looks like a step in the right direction, except that it adds an additional bookmarks bar with duplicated bookmarks, rather than modifies the original standard chrome bookmarks bar. Unfortunately, the duplicated bookmarks are flattened, which destroys folder structures. Additionally, the second bookmarks bar is hidden until the mouse hovers the address bar

Answer (score 0):

I just increased the visibility of my Chrome Bookmarks icons and labels on my laptop running Windows 10 through Windows *Settings → Display → Scale and layout* and changing the size of text, apps, and other items from 100% to 150%. Then returning to Chrome and reducing the zoom to 80%. This makes the text on my bookmarks bar and the text in my browser approximately the same size.